# member action table data model suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to add an action table, but i'm currently at odds as to how to approach the problem.

Before i go into more detail.

We have members who can do different actions on our website

- add an image
- update an image
- rate an image
- post a comment on image
- add a blog post
- update a blog post
- comment on a blog post
- etc, etc

the action table allows our users to "Watch" other member's activities if they want to add them to their watch list.

I currently created a table called **member_actions** with the following columns

```
[UserID] [actionDate] [actionType] [refID]
```

[refID] can be a reference either to the image ID in the DB or blogpost ID, or an id column of another actionable table (eg. event)

[actionType] is an Enum column with action names such as (imgAdd,imgUpdate,blogAdd,blogUpdate, etc...)

[actionDate] will decide which records get deleted every 90 days... so we won't be keeping the actions forever

the current mysql query i cam up with is

```
SELECT act.*, 
        img.Title, img.FileName, img.Rating, img.isSafe, img.allowComment AS allowimgComment,
        blog.postTitle, blog.firstImageSRC AS blogImg, blog.allowComments AS allowBlogComment,
        event.Subject, event.image AS eventImg, event.stimgs, event.ends,
        imgrate.Rating
    FROM member_action act
    LEFT JOIN member_img img ON (act.actionType="imgAdd" OR act.actionType="imgUpdate")
                     AND img.imgID=act.refID AND img.isActive AND img.isReady
    LEFT JOIN member_blogpost blog ON (act.actionType="blogAdd" OR act.actionType="blogUpdate")
                    AND blog.id=act.refID AND blog.isPublished AND blog.isPublic
    LEFT JOIN member_event event ON (act.actionType="eventAdd" OR act.actionType="eventUpdate")
                    AND event.id=act.refID AND event.isPublished
    LEFT JOIN img_rating imgrate ON act.actionType="imgRate" AND imgrate.UserID=act.UserID AND imgrate.imgID=act.refID
    LEFT JOIN member_favorite imgfav ON act.actionType="imgFavorite" AND imgfav.UserID=act.UserID AND imgfav.imgID=act.refID
    LEFT JOIN img_comment imgcomm ON (act.actionType="imgComment" OR act.actionType="imgCommentReply") AND imgcomm.imgID=act.refID
    LEFT JOIN blogpost_comment blogcomm ON (act.actionType="blogComment" OR act.actionType="blogCommentReply") AND blogcomm.blogPostID=act.refID
    ORDER BY act.actionDate DESC
    LIMIT XXXXX,20
```

---

Ok so basically, given that i'll be deleting actions older than 90 days every week or so... would it make sense to go with this query for displaying the member action history?

OR should i add a new text column in **member_actions** table called [actionData] where i can store a few details in json or xml format for fast querying of the member_action table.

It adds to the table size and reduces query complexity, but the table will be purged from periodically from old entries.

the assumption is that eventually we'll have no more than a few 100k members so would i'm concerned about the table size of the member_action table with it's text [actionData] column that will contain some specific details.

I'm leaning towards the [actionData] model but any recommendations or considerations will be appreciated.

another consideration is that it's possible that the table entries for img or blog could get deleted... so i could have action but no reference record...this sure does add to the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are dealing with user interface issues, performance is key.  All the joins will do take time, even with indexes.  And, querying the database is likely to lock records in all the tables (or indexes), which can slow down inserts.

So, I lean towards denormalizing the data, by maintaining the text in the record.

However, a key consideration is whether the text can be updated after the fact.  That is, you will load the data when it is created.  Can it then change?  The problem of maintaining the data in light of changes (which could involve triggers and stored procedures) could introduce a lot of additional complexity.

If the data is static, this is not an issue.  As for table size, I don't think you should worry about that too much.  Databases are designed to manage memory.  It is maintaining the table in a page cache, which should contain pages for currently active members.  You can always increase memory size, especially for 100,000 users which is well within the realm of today's servers.

Comment: another consideration is that it's possible that the table entries for img or blog could get deleted... so i could have action but no reference record...this sure does add to the problem...

Comment: @robert . . . Caching some values might be a partial solution.  You would see the text, but not the underlying object.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be wary of this approach - as you add kinds of actions that you want to monitor the join is going to keep growing (and the sparse extra columns in the select statement as well).

I don't think it would be that scary to have a couple of extra columns in this table - and this query sounds like it would be running fairly frequently, so making it efficient seems like it would be a good idea.

Comment: so.... i'm a bit confused. you think i should go with the [actionData] column for efficiency?

Comment: another consideration is that it's possible that the table entries for img or blog could get deleted... so i have action but no reference record...